# Window Services

Tags: c++, winapi, service

I wrote a simple Windows Service that writes memory information to a text file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define SLEEP_TIME 5000
#define LOGFILE "C:\\MyServices\\memstatus.txt"

SERVICE_STATUS ServiceStatus;
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE hStatus;

void  ServiceMain(int argc, char** argv);
void  ControlHandler(DWORD request);
int InitService();

int WriteToLog(string file_name, string input)
{
    FILE *f;
    fopen_s(&f, file_name.c_str(), "a+");
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", input.c_str());
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}

string N = "MemoryStatus";
LPWSTR Name = new wchar_t(N.size() + 1);

int main()
{
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[2];
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceName = Name;
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceProc = (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain;

    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceName = NULL;
    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceProc = NULL;
    // Start the control dispatcher thread for our service
    StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable);
    return 0;
}


void ServiceMain(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int error;

    ServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32;
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
    ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;

    hStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(
        Name,
        (LPHANDLER_FUNCTION)ControlHandler);
    if (hStatus == (SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE)0)
    {
        // Registering Control Handler failed
        return;
    }
    // Initialize Service 
    error = InitService();
    if (error)
    {
        // Initialization failed
        ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = -1;
        SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
        return;
    }
    // We report the running status to SCM. 
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);

    MEMORYSTATUS memory;
    // The worker loop of a service
    while (ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING)
    {
        char buffer[16];
        GlobalMemoryStatus(&memory);
        sprintf_s(buffer, "%d", memory.dwAvailPhys);
        int result = WriteToLog("TestFile.txt", buffer);
        if (result)
        {
            ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
            ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = -1;
            SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
            return;
        }

        Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    }
    return;
}

// Service initialization
int InitService()
{
    int result;
    result = WriteToLog("TestFile.txt", "Monitoring started.");
    return(result);
}

// Control handler function
void ControlHandler(DWORD request)
{
    switch (request)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
        WriteToLog("TestFile.txt", "Monitoring stopped.");

        ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
        return;

    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
        WriteToLog("TestFile.txt", "Monitoring stopped.");

        ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
        return;

    default:
        break;
    }

    // Report current status
    SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);

    return;
}
```

I installed it successfully, but the Task Manager shows its status as stopped. When I right-click and press the Start button, I get an error that the system could not find the file specified.

Almost all of the examples I have followed from StackOverflow, or anywhere else, have gotten the same error.

Comment: I suggest that you debug your program.

Comment: are you use `__stdcall` default calling convention ? if not - you wrong callback functions use. add direct `__stdcall` to this functions and not use type cast like `(LPHANDLER_FUNCTION)ControlHandler`

Comment: Why are you using a cast here: `ServiceTable[0].lpServiceProc = (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain;` if the calling convetion doesn't match you don't get a warning from the compiler. Never use a cast if not really needed!

Answer (score 0):

When a function does not specify a calling convention (like yours), most C++ compilers default to the `__cdecl` calling convention unless configured with a different default.  However, the Win32 API uses the `__stdcall` calling convention.  You need to add that calling convention to the declarations of your functions that you give to the service API.  You also need to make sure those same functions are also using the correct parameter types, as well (yours are not).

Get rid of the type-casts that are hiding compiler errors from you.  The compiler complains for a reason, don't ignore it.

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#define SLEEP_TIME 5000
#define LOGFILE "C:\\MyServices\\memstatus.txt"

SERVICE_STATUS ServiceStatus = {};
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE hStatus = NULL;

void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR* argv);
void WINAPI ControlHandler(DWORD request);
bool InitService();    

bool WriteToLog(const string &file_name, const string &input)
{
    ofstream f(file_name.c_str(), ios_base::app);
    if (f.is_open())
        f << input << "\n";
    return !f.fail();
}

LPCTSTR Name = TEXT("MemoryStatus");

int main()
{
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[2];
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceName = Name;
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceProc = &ServiceMain;

    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceName = NULL;
    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceProc = NULL;

    // Start the control dispatcher thread for our service
    StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable);

    return 0;
}

void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR* argv)
{
    ServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32;
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
    ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;

    hStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(Name, &ControlHandler);
    if (!hStatus)
    {
        // Registering Control Handler failed
        return;
    }

    // Initialize Service 
    if (!InitService())
    {
        // Initialization failed
        ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = -1;
        SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
        return;
    }

    // We report the running status to SCM. 
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);

    MEMORYSTATUS memory;
    // The worker loop of a service
    while (ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING)
    {
        char buffer[16];
        GlobalMemoryStatus(&memory);
        sprintf_s(buffer, "%d", memory.dwAvailPhys);
        if (!WriteToLog("TestFile.txt", buffer))
        {
            ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
            ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = -1;
            SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
            return;
        }

        Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    }
}

// Service initialization
bool InitService()
{
    return WriteToLog("TestFile.txt", "Monitoring started.");
}

// Control handler function
void WINAPI ControlHandler(DWORD request)
{
    switch (request)
    {
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
            WriteToLog("TestFile.txt", "Monitoring stopped.");
            ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
            ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
            break;

        case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
            WriteToLog("TestFile.txt", "Monitoring stopped.");
            ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
            ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
            break;
        }

        // Report current status
        SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);    
    }
}
```

I suggest you read Microsoft's documentation on how to write a service correctly:

[Service Programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685967.aspx)

[Service Program Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685969.aspx)

[The Complete Service Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540476.aspx)

That being said, you say that your service is unable to start because Windows claims it can't find a file. That implies that you may not be installing the service into the SCM correctly. But you didn't show the actual command-line that you are passing to `sc.exe`. Make sure the `binPath` value you are passing is the correct path to your service EXE.

If you are sure it is, then another possibility could be that your EXE has a dependency on an external DLL that is not located on Windows' search path. That could also cause your EXE to fail to run with a 'file not found" error.

I suggest that you run [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) while trying to start your service. That will show you exactly which file Windows is looking for when the error happens. That will give you a better clue as to where you need to troubleshoot your installation.

---

On a side note, Windows has built-in support for logging.  You don't need to manually write log messages to a text file.  Consider logging messages to the standard Windows Event Viewer using functions like [`ReportEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363679.aspx), [`EventWrite()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363752.aspx), etc.

Comment: I installed service successfully using sc.exe but task manager showed the status as stopped when i start it i got an error message that system could not find the file specified.

Answer (score -2):

You could try a few things for troubleshooting-

1.What is your service image path in the following registry location- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\YourServiceName\ImagePath
2.Check by providing the fully-qualified path of your service executable.